# Truncate Text - Show full text in Tooltip on mouseover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I output a text from my database with the following code:

```
if ($data["own_subject"][$x]!="") { <td><p>".$data["own_subject"][0]."</p></td> }
```

I found a JS function to only show the first 10 characters and once someone does a mouseover the whole text appears. This function is working with the following code and it is working fine:

```
<script>
    var lengthText = 10;
    var text = $('p').text();
    var shortText = $.trim(text).substring(0, lengthText).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";

    $('p').text(shortText);

    $('p').hover(function () {
        $(this).text(text);
    }, function () {
        $(this).text(shortText);
    });
</script>
```

Now I do not like the style of the outcome and I would like to show the full text in some kind of a tooltip. I am using bootstrap and bootstrap has this function. My problem is now that I do not know how I need to change my JS code to show the full length text in a tooltip. Can someone help me out and show me how I need to change my current code?

I would really appreciate your any help.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: simply by using the html attribute `title`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using tooltip of bootstrap

```
   <button id="test" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
```

Tooltip on Bottom

```
$(function() { 
   var lengthText = 10;
   var text = $('#test').text();
   var shortText = $.trim(text).substring(0, lengthText).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";

   $('#test').prop("title", text);
   $('#test').text(shortText);

   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5hHRjULpDlMP3cYhHhU4?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

- Add your original `text` in title attribute of `p` tag which I hope you are already doing.
- Add `data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"` attributes to `p` tag

**Ex**

```
<p data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title='".$data["own_subject"][0]."'>".$data["own_subject"][0]."</p>
```

- Initiate as `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` Also you can now remove `$('p').hover` event.

**Ex**

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `title` attribute with real text to you element and call `bootstraps` `tooltip` init over that elements, also you need to remove current `hover` handler from your script

```
$('p').text(shortText);
// Add title with real text to your element
$('p').attr('title', text);

// And all in document ready bootstrap tooltip init for your short text tags
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('p').tooltip();
});
```

check more about boostrap tolltip here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try simple html tooltip using title.

```
if ($data["own_subject"][$x]!="") { <td><p title='".$data["own_subject"][0]."'>".$data["own_subject"][0]."</p></td> }
```